# How to install archlinux to a file in a NTFS volume?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I want to install archlinux to a file in NTFS volume on a computer with grub2 installed. I can create the file in the archlinux live as this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/rootfs.img bs=65536 count=400000
mke2fs /path/to/rootfs.img
mount /path/to/rootfs.img /mnt/rootfs
pacstrap /mnt/rootfs base
arch-chroot /mnt/rootfs
pacman -Syu

...
```

After I prepared the rootfs.img, I have trouble in make it bootable from grub2

```
set rootfs=/path/to/rootfs.img
loopback loop (hdx,y)$rootfs
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=(hdx,y) loop=$rootfs
initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
```

It cannot mount root partition and complain about no ntfs module

Comment: installing Linux on NTFS is not a good idea [Can Ubuntu Linux be installed on FAT32 or NTFS?](https://superuser.com/q/782849/241386), [How to boot an NTFS Partition in Archlinux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48160859/995714), [Install Ubuntu on a NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/q/55441/253474), [Can I install a Linux program on an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/924190/253474)

Comment: It's not possible to do this without some initramfs trickery (i.e: mounting the image and calling chroot before init starts).